# How to apply theme to jupyter lab

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I tried to apply dark theme by putting a *.css file in the ~/.jupyter/custom/ directory (like [here](http://sherifsoliman.com/2016/01/11/theming-ipython-jupyter-notebook/)). This changes a theme for a normal jupyter notebook. But no affect on the jupyter lab appearance. I also tried to install a theme using jupyter-theme, but alas, no changes in jupyter lab appearance.

Can someone point me to the how-to guide?

Comment: are you trying to embed the jupyter lab to your website?

Comment: No, just to set-up my local jupyter lab.

Comment: try [jupyter themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes)

Comment: Actually I tried, and it works. For a notebook. So to say if I run jupyter notebook - the selected theme works. But if I run jupyter lab - it does not. Also jupyter lab has theme settings for the editor, and they work. Notebooks in the lab have a default appearance.

Comment: Some time passed and I found a github discussion on the topic, started one month before my question:
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1084

And a duplicate discussion (closed): https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2102

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**UPDATE** 02/03/2018
Now this option is already built in in the settings menu!

[image]

Recently this issue was closed on the GitHub, and finally it is possible to edit settings of the jupyter lab. Hurray!

**The procedure is described in this [pull request](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/2759)**.

Just update your jupyter-lab (now it is version 0.27.0) and go to File - Settings, then select Theme tab. And type your theme name in the User Overrides and press the check-mark at the right of the string. I tried several, but only "theme": "JupyterLab Dark" seems to work. Enough for me.

[image: Apply dark theme to jupyter lab]

[image]

I really appreciate the work the jupyter team is doing. Thank you all!

Answer (score 16):

I bit the bullet, and figured out how to write a full custom theme as an extension.

The process is:

1. Copy the Light theme from `jupyterlab/packages` to your own repository.
2. Edit the package metadata in `package.json` and `src/index.ts`
3. Edit the CSS stylesheets in `styles`
4. Install the theme using `jupyter labextensions install .`

   - You may need to manually generate dependencies using `node`

Here is my theme for future reference - https://github.com/nfultz/jupyterlab-theme-simple-extension

EDIT:

There's now a cookiecutter template to make it easier: https://github.com/jupyterlab/theme-cookiecutter

Comment: I believe, `labextensions` is singular. So it would be: `jupyter labextension install .`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open jupyter lab
2. Go to -> Settings -> Theme -> JupyterLab Dark

You can select your desired theme