# How to change the layout of an active cell in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, jupyter

Currently, the active cell doesn't change apart from a blue bar showing on the side.

[image]
It would be good if the active cell was more prominent. For example, how can I have a border around the cell like the border in Jupyter notebook? Or change the background to a darker grey?

Comment: See if [jupyter-themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes) may help, either one of the themes in there or something you customize.

Comment: @jdehesa They don't seem to work for Jupyter Lab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518614/how-to-apply-theme-to-jupyter-lab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to create a file `custom.css` with the content:

```
<style>
    .jp-mod-active .jp-CodeMirrorEditor {
        border: var(--jp-border-width) solid var(--jp-cell-editor-active-border-color);
    }
</style>
```

Then, run the following:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
with open('./custom.css', 'r') as f: style = f.read()
HTML(style)
```

And now the active cell will have a blue border:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That's almost perfect. It doesn't work for markup cells though. Would it be possible to have the markup cells highlighted the same way?

Comment: Is there a workaround to not have to put the Python code in a cell, but somewhere else in case you don't want to show that code to the audience when presenting the notebook?