# How do I launch jupyter lab with the dark theme enabled by default?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518614/how-to-apply-theme-to-jupyter-lab) points out that the "JupyterLab Dark" theme is now available as part of a vanilla `jupyter-lab` install.

How can I configure `jupyter-lab` so that it launches with this theme already applied *on the first launch*, so I don't have to manually select it every time I launch my jupyter docker container?

Comment: You should ask here https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this in `~/.jupyterlab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/themes.jupyterlab-settings`

```
{
    "theme": "JupyerLab Dark"
}
```

In the Dockerfile this might look like:

```
RUN mkdir -p ~/.jupyterlab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/ && \
    echo '{ "theme":"JupyterLab Dark" }' > themes.jupyterlab-settings
```

Comment: In saturncloud.io you need to change URL a little bit from @mike.
mkdir -p ~/.jupyter/lab/jupyterlab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/ && echo '{ "theme":"JupyterLab Dark" }' > themes.jupyterlab-settings

Comment: A couple of issues... the path seems to be `~/jupyter/lab/user-settings...` now with the extra slash. And whilst the `mkdir` makes the directory, the `echo` actually writes in the current directory if you don't `cd` there first.

Answer (score 8):

As the answer from mike and the comment from MarkusOdenthal did not work for me when I used the jupyter docker stacks I looked for a different solution and it seams using `overrides.json` is the current recommended approach:

https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/directories.html#overridesjson

In short:
check the application directory with `jupyter lab path` and place a file named `overrides.json` containing

```json
{
    "@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:themes": {
        "theme": "JupyterLab Dark"
    }
}
```

into `<application directory>/settings/` (e.g. `/opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab/settings/` for the official jupyter docker containers)

So if you want to have the base image from jupyter with dark theme, the Dockerfile would be

```
FROM jupyter/base-notebook

COPY overrides.json /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab/settings/
```