# How can I set my custom jupyterlab theme extension as the default on launch through docker

Tags: docker, themes, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I made 2 custom theme extensions using the tutorial on jupyter website.  They both work and I can click on them through jupyter lab settings.  However, I want one of them to be the default theme upon opening jupyterlab, not the default jupyter light theme.  How can I do this?  Is something required in the docker file?  I have tried making overrides.json file but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you placing the `overrides.json` in the proper place? For example like [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/overrides-json-not-working-in-z2jh/13570/2?u=fomightez)?

Comment: And what did you put in the overrides.json?

Comment: @krassowski In the overrides.json file I put {"theme": "/path/to/extension/My-Light-Theme"} and I placed the overrides file in /data/home/myusername/.jupyter/lab/user-settings, yet it doesn't invoke the theme upon launch of jupyter lab.

Comment: This is incorrect format you need to add package name stanza first, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70485739/6646912

Comment: @krassowski So now I have {
        "@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:themes":{
                "theme": "/data/home/username/path-to-extension/My-Light-Theme"
        }
} but still it doesn't change the theme on opening.  Is there another step to this I am missing?

Comment: You should not put a path to extension there but the theme id I believe