Micro level changes to Jupyter Lab theme
I know I can change the theme in Jupyter Lab to make it light or dark. And that I can change the background color of a single cell. But I want to make some further micro level changes to the overall theme, such as:

Change the default background color of a code cell
Remove the gray border around the cell
The blue line number should be gray
Finally change the blue bar on the left of the currently selected cell to something other than blue.


Most of the solutions I've seen pertain to Jupyter Notebook.

You may have some luck with https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/jupyterlab-theme-editor but in principle you would want to create a new theme inheriting from an existing theme, see https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_dev.html#theme-plugins

You can use a custom.css file which is available since JupyterLab 4.2. It requires starting jupyterlab with --custom-css flag. This is documented in the User Guide under Applying Custom CSS.
If you do not know CSS, you may have some luck with jupyterlab-theme-editor (for screenshots see this post on the Jupyter blog).
In principle for anything production-ready you would want to create a new theme inheriting from an existing theme. I think jupyterlab-theme-editor can help you to get started but otherwise I would recommend looking though the JupyterLab extension documentation, especially theme plugins and CSS sections.

this is for Jupiter Lab only, i am helping you to change further
check here

check this file, edit your self, as i am ok with the old one, i am not customizing myself it is default file look.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

you can use jupiterthemes
if you are using Anaconda
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterthemes

or for pip you can try this
pip install jupyterthemes

check you required theme there if no then use customize setting to change yourself!
if not let us know in little detail manner, instead of colors the theme name example: neaon and all

AFAIK (and I've tried) jupyterthemes works with jupyter notebook, not jupyter lab.

ok if you are using only the jupiter lab then try
Settings, then select Theme tab. And type your theme name in the User Overrides and press the check-mark at the right of the string. I tried several, but only "theme": "JupyterLab Dark" seems to work. Enough for me.
this i got from the other answer y dont you look in to that that helps you for more detail refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219796/11716825

If you would read my problem, as I explained in the first line: "I know you can change the theme to make it light or dark". I want to make further changes to that over all theme.
